# How do I reinterpret a uint64_t variable bits as a double as opposed to static_cast?

Tags: c++11, reinterpret-cast

```
uint64 value = 0x543;
double dval = *reinterpret_cast<double*>(&value);
```

I want dval to be of a certain value which when written in hexadecimal looks like this "0x543". Is there any danger doing this? Do you see a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: There's a danger of not getting the value you expect. What value do you expect `dval` to be?

Comment: I want dval to be of a certain value which when written in hexadecimal looks like this 0x543.

Comment: On my platform `dval` == 6.65506e-321.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast). In fact, the shown example is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.